# Dynamic Oracle query to generate a select count over classes in table

Tags: python, sql, oracle, dynamic

Hello I am trying to generate the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT <id> FROM <class1> 
UNION ALL 
SELECT <id> 
FROM <class2> 
UNION ALL 
SELECT <id> FROM <class3>);
```

The problem I have is that there is not always the same number of classes (3 classes in the example), some time I have to count over 1 class some times more in a random manner depends on the provider, on top of it id is not always the same also depend on the provider.

as I am more familiar with python thas SQL what I am currently doing is looking for the classes in a table

`SELECT DISTINCT <column_name> FROM <classes_table> WHERE <identifier> =####;`
copy the classes paste them into an excel sheet and run this python code

```
#import library
import pandas as  pd
#read csv and import as dataframe 
df = pd.read_csv('clases.csv')
#define function
def query_generator_count(id):
    """
    takes listing and returns querys for counting files
    """
    #begining of query 
    start = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ('
    #initialize empty list
    list_ = []
    #initialize counter 
    count = 0
    #loop trhough classes column in dataframe 
    for class_ in df['classes']:
        #if there is more than one class append union to query      
        if count < len(df) - 1:
            query = 'SELECT '+id+' FROM '+ str(class_)+ ' UNION ALL'
       # else just count over one class
        else:
            query = 'SELECT '+id+' FROM '+ str(class_)+ ');'

        list_.append(query)
      

    count = count +1  
    query_1 = ' '.join(list_)
    query_final = start + query_1
    return(query_final)
print(query_generator_count(id))
```

I have been reading about dynamic queries but I cannot get my hand around them but I know its possible to do the same as my python code does but directly in my database saving me the time to selecting copying pasting and running a code outside the database if someone can help me put this idea into a dynamic oracle query would be amazing thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you even have more "class" tables? That has a certain smell on it. Could be that your schema design needs severe improvement and there should only be one "class" table with a column for the number.

Comment: you can replace column name with 1 so you won't be dependent on a columnname to count , so for ex your query qould be like  `SELECT 1 FROM '+ str(class_)+ ');' `

Comment: This is more a *misunderstanding* that a *smell* @stickybit. In `ORM` lingo could a *class table* mean simple a table used to store objects of a specific class. Additionally, to report counts of rows from several tables in one query is IMHO not an uncommon use case.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber: Well, yes *if* it means that, that translates to one table per entity and that's how it (usually) should be. But the occasions where you need to `UNION` (parts of) *different* entities are probably pretty rare. Let alone the need to do that for a varying set of entities. That makes your interpretation less likely, I think. Though it's not impossible of course.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `SQL` only solution that work similar or better.

Let assume this is you `classes_table` - I'm ignoring the `identifier` selection.

```
select * from classes_table;

TABL
----
TAB1
TAB2
TAB3
```

This query get the definition from the `classes_table` and returns the required `count` query.

```
with tabs as (
select 
  'select id from ' ||table_name as sql_txt,
  table_name
from  classes_table)
select 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
'||
listagg(sql_txt, ' UNION ALL'||chr(10) ) within group (order by table_name) ||'
);' as sql_txt
from tabs;
```

The result is one row with following SQL statement

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
select id from TAB1 UNION ALL
select id from TAB2 UNION ALL
select id from TAB3
);
```

**Some Discusion**

You may replace the `id`column with `1` as suggested in *comments* if you only wants to count rows.

The limitation of the approach with `listagg` that concatenates the single `selects` is that the result is limited with 4000 bytes.

If you have a large number of tables that would cross it, use a Q&D solution with the folowing query:

```
select 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (' as sql_text  from dual
union all
select 
  'select id from ' ||table_name||' union all' as sql_txt 
from  classes_table
```

This query returns one row for each table and is not in valid syntax - you'll have to replace the last `union all` with the string  `);`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
select id from TAB1 union all
select id from TAB2 union all
select id from TAB3 union all
```